# How to properly monitor the number of PostgreSQL database connections?

Tags: postgresql, performance, monitoring

I tried to use a Nagios script for monitoring the number of database connections on a Postgres database and I reached this problem: these are counted as currently open-connections and measured every 5 minutes.

```
SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;
```

Still, this seems to miss a huge number of short-lived connections, so the statistics are far from the reality.

I tried to run the script manually and I observed big changes even between two connections made few seconds away one from another.

How could I get this information in a reliable way? like max(connectios) happened during a time interval.

Comment: Aggregate stats over time for connections would be nice, but I don't think PostgreSQL currently collects them. Look at the docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html for details.

Comment: @CraigRinger maybe I could configure Postgres or the clients to keep connections open for a longer period of time, so I could measure them. Due to the current setup I had one case when the postgres started to refuse connections. Monitoring was not able to detect this because this happened inside the 5 minute interval, and it went from below warning level to above critical in less then 5 minutes. And this was not a DoS attack.

Comment: Yeah, that's quite an interesting problem. I strongly recommend putting a `PgBouncer` in front of your PostgreSQL instance, it'll queue up connections when it's too busy instead of rejecting them. (Yes, it's stupid that PostgreSQL can't do that its self but it's not a simple fix; see the endless discussions on the mailing lists re built-in pooling).

Comment: Please post to pgsql-general asking about this. Link back to this post. If nobody has any better suggestions, propose a TODO item for it, that way we can keep track of it and someone who's doing stats work later might pick it up.

Comment: What about logging connections (using `log_connections ` and `log_disconnections`) into the logfile (e.g. csvlog) and then use pgBadger or something similar to extract that from the logfile?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good point. You can even "tail" the logs with a client that just reads new log entries, integrating over disconnects and connects to get a near-real-time report of peak connections during a given timeframe. Frankly, it shouldn't be this complicated. One of my tasks for the AXLE project (http://axleproject.eu) is to implement some more auditing, and I might be able to fit this into it...

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use Workload monitoring tools like `pgbadger` for checking database connections and overall load. It will help you understand which users are connecting for how much time and what queries are being fired by them. For information on installing and configuring pgbadger, refer [this](https://www.dhis2.org/analysing-postgresql-logs-using-pgbadger) page.

If you just want to check the number of active connections, you can use
 `select count(*) from pg_stat_activity where state='active'`

Answer (score 1):

The [Postgres 14 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html) contain an information that suggests that the necessary information has been added to Posgres 14 (see section "E.8.3.1.7. System Views"):

> Add session statistics to the pg_stat_database system view (Laurenz Albe)

The corresponding [documentation on monitoring stats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW) mentions a few new columns for the `pg_stat_database` table:

[image]

If my understanding of the documentation is correct, these should contain cumulative statistics of the database connections. This would mean that it is possible to monitor a database based on these aggregates now. One could query the database in intervals, and determine e.g. the number of connections within the interval by taking the difference of the `sessions` value. Unfortunately this also wouldn't deliver the true peak of max(connection) within the interval, but at least it can narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension with local_preload_libraries to do this.

Something like this:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include <string.h>

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

void _PG_init(void)
{
  SPI_connect();
  int ret = SPI_execute("UPDATE logon_logs SET logged = logged + 1", false, 0);
  SPI_finish();
}

/*
 * _PG_fini
 * Uninstall the hook.
 */
void _PG_fini(void)
{
}
```

Or instead UPDATE via NOTIFY

Comment: Please, try to improve your answer with some explanation on how to proceed.